# Find question about integration of rational functions.

Tags: support, search

Is there a question in MSE with an answer containing the whole integration process for rational functions (on the reals)?

Questions on the topic appear frequently. Every time I try to find a link to the complete algorithm I can never find it; even elsewhere. Speaking of which; it would also work if someone knows another place in the Internet that has it.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20963/integration-by-partial-fractions-how-and-why-does-it-work/21112#21112).

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat: I can't seem to post this as an answer, even when I pad it with additional verbiage.  Maybe I need more additional verbiage...

Comment: See also [Hermite reduction.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/641091/242) and Bronstein's [Symbolic integration tutorial.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.218.9438&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: @WillOrrick Okay, I posted it. For the future: you can put any amount of irrelevant verbiage (e.g., copying the whole question into answer box); if  removed  within 5 minutes of posting, it leaves no trace.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer by Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21112), found by Will Orrick, contains an extensive description of the integration of rational functions.

Comment: But that is far from the most efficient way to proceed. See the links in my comment.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that this answer is in the [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions).